# Adding a data attribute to filtered items using Mixitup

Tags: javascript, html, css, filtering, mixitup

I have a current project using [Mixitup](https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/) to filter content. I have a need for the remaining elements inherit specific CSS styles, and vice-versa. It seems the only way I can possibly do this is add a data attribute onto non-hidden items as Mixitup cannot remove elements from the DOM.

Here's an example of what filtered content would look like. Mixitup adds the inline style to hide elements when filters are selected from the `<ul class="filter-list">`:

```
<ul class="filter-list">
  <li><a class="filter" href="#" data-filter=".filter-1">Filter 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="filter" href="#" data-filter=".filter-2">Filter 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="items">
  <div class="mix filter-1 filter-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="mix filter-2 filter-item"></div>
  <div class="mix filter-1 filter-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="mix filter-2 filter-item"></div>
</div>
```

This uses the following config for Mixitup:

```
var mixer = mixitup('.items');
var mixer = mixitup(containerEl);

var mixer = mixitup(containerEl, {
    selectors: {
        target: '.filter-item'
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 300
    }
});
```

This works as expected, but ideally I'd like to extend this further so I get the following result:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="mix filter-1 filter-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="mix filter-2 filter-item" data-order="1"></div>
  <div class="mix filter-1 filter-item" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="mix filter-2 filter-item" data-order="2"></div>
</div>
```

Ideally the `data-order` attribute increases by 1 for each remaining element.

Here's a Codepen with an ongoing prototype: http://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/ygWayB/

Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: css can do this nowdays using labels and checbox or radio buttons , reminds me of an old dabblet i turned in a codepen years ago http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JFdEk it uses lorempixel images and sorts them by family (*tous* means *all*, -- , *aucune* means *none* ;) ) class are used to hide/show them. no js

Comment: found another old example with target http://dabblet.com/gist/4641739 . It is only for the screen while the previous example build inside a form (css would work without a form) can be process if a choice is to be made and togo further with that choice :)